# Web Api Ignoring Route Attribute

Tags: c#, webapi

I am working on a Web API project and when I run it and try to use the route for a controller, it doesn't work and instead, it throws me a 404 error. Why is the Web API ignoring the route attribute?

I'll leave the code below:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]

public class Controller3 : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceContract3 _interest;
    public Controller3(IServiceContract3 interest)
    {
        _interest = interest;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [Route("api/Interest/GetInterests")]
    public IEnumerable<Interest> GetEmployees()
    {
        return _interest.GetInterests();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [Route("api/Interest/AddInterest")]
    public IActionResult AddInterest(Interest interest)
    {
        _interest.AddInterest(interest);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [Route("api/Interest/UpdateInterest")]
    public IActionResult UpdateInterest(Interest interest)
    {
        _interest.UpdateInterest(interest);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [Route("api/Interest/DeleteInterest")]
    public IActionResult DeleteInterest(int id)
    {
        var existingInterest = _interest.GetInterest(id);
        if (existingInterest != null)
        {
            _interest.DeleteInterest(existingInterest.Id);
            return Ok();
        }
        return NotFound($"Employee Not Found with ID : {existingInterest.Id}");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetInterest")]
    public Interest GetInterest(int id)
    {
        return _interest.GetInterest(id);
    }

}
```

And for my Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContextPool<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        context.Database.Migrate();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

How can I fix the routing? Every time I try to do it in my browser like https://localhost:44316/api/Interest/GetInterests I get a 404 error instead. Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens when you go to the `http` address instead?

Comment: Where is `IServiceContract3` being registered for dependency injection?

Answer (score 1):

Typically controllers for a webapi are defined as so:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public sealed class InterestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceContract3 _interest;

    public InterestController(IServiceContract3 interest)
    {
        _interest = interest;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("GetInterests")]
    public IActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
        // this is located at: GET api/Interest/GetInterests
        return Ok(_interest.GetInterests());
    }


    [HttpPost, Route("AddInterest")]
    public IActionResult AddInterest([FromBody] Interest interest)
    {
        // this is located at: POST api/Interest/AddInterest
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("UpdateInterest")]
    public IActionResult UpdateInterest([FromBody] Interest interest)
    {
        // this is located at: POST api/Interest/UpdateInterest
    }

    [HttpDelete, Route("DeleteInterest/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteInterest([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        // this is located at: DELETE api/Interest/DeleteInterest/{id}
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("GetInterest/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetInterest([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        // this is located at: GET api/Interest/GetInterest/{id}
        return Ok(_interest.GetInterest(id));
    }
}
```

First, you want to name your controller a relevant name that will carry throughout the rest of your controller. So, this this case, I changed `Controller3` to `InterestController`. Since the route of the controller is `"/api/[Controller]"`, it will translate to `"api/Interest"`.

Next, remove the `[Action]` attributes. You do not need them in this scenario.

Then, make sure your routes are correct. If you are passing an ID, define your ID in the route using `{id}` and setting the `[FromRoute]` attribute for clarity. Also, use `[FromBody]` to define parameters that will be coming from the body. A lot of these are "default" (meaning you don't *need* to add them), but it helps with clarity.

Finally, if you are using the `IActionResult` pattern, then stick with that through your controller. Don't mix/match return types across endpoints because it's confusing for maintenance.

One final thing:
Your controller endpoint names are slightly redundant. For example, you could do this:

```cs
    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public IActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
        // this is located at: GET api/Interest
        return Ok(_interest.GetInterests());
    }


    [HttpPut, Route("")]
    public IActionResult AddInterest([FromBody] Interest interest)
    {
        // this is located at: PUT api/Interest/
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("")]
    public IActionResult UpdateInterest([FromBody] Interest interest)
    {
        // this is located at: POST api/Interest/
    }

    [HttpDelete, Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteInterest([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        // this is located at: DELETE api/Interest/{id}
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetInterest([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        // this is located at: GET api/Interest/{id}
        return Ok(_interest.GetInterest(id));
    }
```

i.e.: Use the "HTTP Verb" to your advantage to segregate actions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix your route by making api a root. Replace "api" by "~/api". IMHO  you should remove [action] from actions and add it to a controller. Also fix a controller name

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("~/api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class  InterestController : ControllerBase

    [HttpGet("~/api/Interest/GetInterests")]
    public IEnumerable<Interest> GetEmployees()
     ....

   
    [HttpPost("~/api/Interest/AddInterest")]
    public IActionResult AddInterest(Interest interest)
    ...

    
    [HttpPost("~/api/Interest/UpdateInterest")]
    public IActionResult UpdateInterest(Interest interest)
     ...

    
    [HttpDelete("~/api/Interest/DeleteInterest/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteInterest(int id)
    ....

    [HttpGet("~/api/Interest/GetInterest/{id}")]
    public Interest GetInterest(int id)
```